# Android Studio: Have text and image inside a button

Tags: image, button, android-studio

In the button I am designing I need to create a button that informs the user they are leaving the mobile application to a web page out of the app.

I want to have an image representing exporting and text with in the button.

I completed this in xcode. Is it possible to do this in Android studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Button` class extends `TextView` class which has the feature called [Compound Drawables](https://sriramramani.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/compound-drawables/). That's a drawable which can be placed on either side of the text: on the right/left/top/bottom. Example:

```
<Button
    android:text="@string/example"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/btn_example"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp" />
```

I think this is what you're looking for.

**Edit:** the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34320463/885028) of Jim has to be considered **only** when you have no other option. Google advocates against this approach, more info can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/custom-views/optimizing-view.html). In short: the more layouts/views you have, the slower performance you achieve. Android Studio even shows you the warning in the xml editor saying you should use compound drawables wherever possible and use `ImageView`+`TextView` bundle only as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

In Android, you can make any `Layout` capture `onClick` events. So you could use a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` and put a `TextView` and an `ImageView` in it. With proper formatting, images, etc. this layout will appear like a button.

Also, you will want to look at `selector` if you want the "button" to change when it "pressed" "focused" etc.

Comment: I was intending on keeping the text and image in the button at the same time.

Comment: This does that - the `CompoundDrawables` suggestion is also a good one, but it had limitations that you may discover will not work for your use-case. I usually avoid it for that reason.